# Get the call tree for a form

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration

I have a VB project which has set of forms. There are number of class modules/common modules files inside that project.

I want to generate the tree hierarchy for each form.

Assume there are 10 forms f1, f2 .... f10. Form f1 is having fun1, fun2... fun5 functions.

I want to see the tree hiearchy at form level. This means what all functions are being called from each form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in function like that in VB6 IDE.

You need a third-party tool like http://www.aivosto.com/project/project.html to analyze your code.

I've used the Project Analyzer before and it's quite good. The standard edition should be good enough for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the VB6 IDE then I believe you can use the Object Browser window to do what you want.  You can select a form (or class or module) in the project and it will show the contained functions.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have both VB6 & VS 2010 on my machine. I want to view the complete call tree for the given function of any form. For e.g form f1 is having function (fun1) which in turn calls some function in class module, followed by some function in bas module. I want to see the this hierarchy. Atul